# LAMP WordPress Permalinks 404 error

Tags: permalinks

I have an Ubuntu 16 VPS running (LAMP) Apache+WordPress .

the permalinks are not functioning properly as i'm receiving 404 errors.

Hello,  the following .htaccess files exist on the server:

/var/www/html/wp-snapshots/.htaccess
/var/www/html/wp-includes/.htaccess
/var/www/html/.htaccess
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/lib/vendor/mrclay/minify/.htaccess

/var/www/html/.htaccess contains, the code below.

The WordPress settings are also set to " Post name ", and the url is still returning a 404 error:
http://45.77.185.160/change-your-booking/?booking_hash=42fc52073d89cce21451a2b2e71e1f1a&booking_pay=1

Comment: You might want to update the permalink settings, even if you didn't change them. This is a very popular problem, with a very simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Though there are many possibilities like enable Apache web server with the mod_rewrite or check permissions to allow Wordpress to write to the .htaccess file.

It will be helpful for you, if you go through this for more details. https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Answer (score 0):

Create `.htaccess` file in your WordPress folder and put below values:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Get more information about `.htaccess` in WordPress
https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess